# How can I send intents to other activities or services without starting it?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I want to send some data across activities and services.

I try to use `PendingIntent.send()` to send my data, but as soon as I call `PendingIntent.send()`, all my services starts to work. I don't want them to be called by `PendingIntent.send()`.

Should I use other methods? Or should I put all the information I need into a big Bundle and the transfer it between classes?

Comment: Explain your motivation clearly. You want to send data, but you don't want any activity or service to use it? What's the point of sending then?

Comment: actually, my app : act1 --> service1-->service2-->act2 I want each class to be triigered automatically my their mechanism, not by PendingIntent.send().
Service1,Service2, and Act2 needs data from Act1. So I'm trying to let them start automatically.
Is this motivation clear enough? I know it sounds strange...

Answer (score 1):

Register a broadcast receiver where you want to receive messages. Then with context.sendBroadcast(Intent); send intent with the necessary data. You can use IntentFilters to filter the messages and what kind of messages the receiver can fetch.